# Dynamic URL rewriting using codeigniter/php/htaccess when change in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I have URL like base_url()/controller/rowtitle-rowid.

Where this URL is manipulated using function and arranged according to row in database.

As mentioned above I need to change whole URL when I am changing rowid in the URL, that means it should rewrite to particular id of row in database.

For example:

Consider following URLs

1. https://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/medical-device-testing-market-**254474064**.html

2.https://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/timing-relay-market-**241993160**.html

if I change bold numbers in number 2 URL to bold numbers in number 1 URL then it will rewrite the URL to URL number 1 and redirect to URL number 1

Can this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your say you are modifying the `rowid` which I assume are the numbers you are bolding in your 1,2 statements, and at the same time you want to redirect to a different slug and `rowid` which is the dashed statement before the `rowid` at the end of the url e.g. `some-page-name`.

I'm not sure what the `rowid` has to do with anything, perhaps it's just a random int to make sure you don't have duplicate slugs, but it isn't strictly required as long as you increment your titles if you have duplicates like `some-page-name` and `some-page-name-1`.

In PHP and codeigniter what you are trying to do is indeed possible as long as you keep a database with all the iterations of the `slug`. Then in your `Market-Reports` controller you just look for the most recent iteration of the `slug` and serve that as a link to the user. Or if the user is coming from a search engine, on the say `Market-Reports` single page controller to `timing-relay-market-241993160` you query the database where `rowid = 'someid'` and order by `created` or something and then redirect the user to that slug which would be `medical-device-testing-market-254474064.`

Further if your database table for keeping track of slugs has the following rows `rowid`, `rowtitle`, `fullslug` you could literally just use `intval()` to get the `rowid` from the fullslug and do the same type of thing as I just outlined in the previous paragraph.

NOTE: You cannot do this with static HTML pages. I am assuming since you tagged PHP and codeigniter you are using php and controllers.

Comment: Hi @alex thank you for your response, but it is not cleared to me when you say rowid is just a random number whereas rowid is primary key for that row in the table. According to this rowid I need to change whole URL as http://www/base_url/controller/rowtitle1-rowid1 .